# Add empty unused class names to react components

Tags: reactjs, webpack, webpack-style-loader

At the moment unused classNames are automatically removed from my components, if I don't use them and "fill" them with CSS. I am developing a widget which can be used on foreign websites and want the give the users the possibility to write custom CSS on their website to effect the widget. On some places the classNames should base on an ID (like `className={'question-'+question_id}`.

I don't know which part of my webpack is responsible for the removing of the classes. How can I disable it or better: How can I tell webpack to NOT remove this special classes?

```
const path = require('path');
const loaderUtils = require('loader-utils');

const HtmlWebPackPlugin = require("html-webpack-plugin");
const DotenvPlugin = require('webpack-dotenv-plugin');

const htmlWebpackPlugin = new HtmlWebPackPlugin({
  template: "./src/index.html",
  filename: "./index.html",
  inject: "head"
});

const dotEnvPlugin = new DotenvPlugin({
  sample: './.env.default',
  path: './.env'
});

const getLocalIdent = (loaderContext, localIdentName, localName, options) => {
  .....
};

module.exports = {
  output: {
    library: 'XLVNT',
    libraryTarget: 'umd',
    umdNamedDefine: true,
    filename: 'x.js',
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: "babel-loader"
          },
        ]
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: "style-loader"
          },
          {
            loader: "css-loader",
            options: {
              modules: true,
              localIdentName: 'x-[folder]-[local]',
              getLocalIdent: getLocalIdent,
            }
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        test: /\.scss$/,
        use: [
          "style-loader",
          {
            loader: "css-loader",
            options: {
              modules: true,
              localIdentName: 'x-[folder]-[local]',
              getLocalIdent: getLocalIdent,
            }
          } ,
          "sass-loader"
        ]
      },
      {
          test: /\.(pdf|jpg|png|gif|svg|ico)$/,
          use: [
              {
                  loader: 'url-loader'
              },
          ]
      },
    ]
  },
  plugins: [dotEnvPlugin, htmlWebpackPlugin]
};
```

Comment: Maybe that's a typo in your post, but maybe not: `className={'question-'.question_id}` - that's not how strings are concatenated in JS, you should use `+` sign. In your example, you try to get `question_id` property of String prototype (code is valid, so there's not syntax), in result className={undefined} so it won't appear in code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want someone to use your component, or a library of components, you should think more in "props" rather than in css classes for style customization.

If you need the users of your Widget to be able to completely manipulate the style of your component, you have many options without having to preemptively write classNames on all your elements.

The most common I have found is to make your component receive a property `altClass` or `className` and then use it inside your component wrapper. This way the users can assign a class to control the styles themselves.

This property could even be an object, that contains a bunch of css key/values that you can apply the same way but to multiple elements in your component.

I hope this answers your question.

If you want inspiration, you should check some open-source UI libraries like [Material UI](https://material-ui.com/) or [Ant Design](https://ant.design/), they handle this kind of scenarios pretty well.

---

Let's put React aside for a second.
Imagine you have a function that receives two arguments: `id` and `className`.
The *id* is from an element on your user page
The className is a string corresponding to a class that is going to be used to customize things.

*webpack.config.js*

```
var path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  entry: './src/index.js',
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
    filename: 'colorme.js',
    library: 'colorme'
  }
};
```

*index.js*

```
export function addThings(id, className) {
  document.getElementById(id)
    .innerHTML = (
      '<div class="'+ className +'">Testing things</div>'
    )
}
```

This function `addThings` will inject inside your element (of `id`) a div with a configurable `className`.

Then, in your users page:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
      .asd {
        background-color: red;
      }
      .awd {
        background-color: blue;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="test"></div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="./colorme.js"></script>
    <script>
      window.colorme.addThings('test', 'asd')
      // window.colorme.addThings('test', 'awd')
      // ...
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

You will see that "Testing things" div is added, with class "asd" or "awd" respectively. And now your users can control how that div looks.

If this works for you, read more here: https://webpack.js.org/guides/author-libraries/

---

If passing options is a big deal, you could use data-* attributes perhaps, like this:

```
<style>
  .asd {
    background-color: red;
  }
  .awd {
     background-color: blue;
  }
</style>
<div data-root_class="asd" data-some_other_class="lala" id="test"></div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="./colorme.js"></script>
<script> colorme.init('test') </script>
```

Comment: Hi Luciano, I think you misunderstood me. The "user" don't use my components as library on the "React-Layer" the just include my built .js to their website and see the widget. Like a Weather-Widget, Facebook Widget, etc... And then they should be able to customize the style of the widget with CSS.

Comment: @rakete I edited my answer to add more info, I hope this time is more or less what you are looking for!

Comment: Perfect! At the moment the user has already has the option to pass options. So I can define new options like "cancel_button_class" and do something like this in my components className={ classnames(styles.cancelButton, option.cancel_button_class}. This way, I think the cancel_button_class is not processed by the webpack purifier (or whatever doing the clean up). This would have the nice side-effect, that I can now hash and shorten my classnames and I exactly can define, which elements, classes can be styles by the user.

Any experiences with options in React? Would you save them to redux?

Comment: well these options, commonly called props, can be used to dispatch a redux action without problem. In fact, in react-redux you can use a `mapStateToProps` function that will receive `state` and `ownProps` arguments, and then all of that is returned in that function can be accessed as a prop inside your React component. https://react-redux.js.org/introduction/quick-start

Answer (score 0):

First thing that looks a bit wrong here is the class name concatenation. Please use es6 string literals. Shown below:

```
className={`question-.${question_id}`}
```

Apart from this, can you try using `classnames` from https://github.com/JedWatson/classnames

Please let me know if this helps.